# Reading data from sql server into excel sheet via Web Service

Tags: sql-server, web-services, excel

consider you have an existing excel worksheet, which needs to load data from sqlserver. The data is normalized, so reading from a table is not an option. Btw, it's Excel 2010.

I tried to provide the data via **stored procedure**, but since I have to do some **data transformation**, SPs are not an option.

The next idea is to provide the data via **web service**. I read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd819156%28v=office.12%29.aspx) but I don't like the result, because the content of the worksheet is written in the .Net code. The solution I'd prefer would be some kind of **data provider**, which can be used directly in the excel sheet, similar to reading data directly from a table.

Is there a way to achieve that?

**Edit**
Because of the first comments and answers. Consider as data transformation e.g. a conversion from ticks (`long`) to `DateTime`. I've to do it in .net, because the result depends on the target time zone.

Comment: I use an add-in to get SQL data, I pass it a connection string and sql statement (eg. `SELECT * FROM [MyView]`) and it loads data into the active workbook (with any number of columns/rows/datatypes).
If you want to go down this route I can post code?

Comment: No sorry, I need to pass it to .net code. Please refer to my post, I added some explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this if i read your question correctly:

Create a new excel sheet document, use the 'From other sources' selection under the 'Data' tab in the new excel sheet, provide your SQL details and connect to the data you need to display in the excel sheet.

You can also use the 'Import and Export Data' tool that is installed with SQL Server. It is a fairly simple process, and the tool walks you through the necessary steps to export the data to an excel sheet.

If you need to do this in application code, you can use a custom database view which returns your processed data and custom columns, invoke this DB view from code, retrive the data rows and write to an excel sheet file. The following link shows how to do this in C#: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-export.htm

Comment: Hmm, well your first point...wouldn't work due to the required data transformation. The second option fails with the data transformation and the fact that it doesn't consider the existing excel sheet. Well and the last option doesn't fit because I don't want to write the Excel sheet in .net code. But thank you anyway.